# Delete all row who are not in an UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that i wanna UPDATE with another table so i have something like :

```
UPDATE table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.fk_table1 SET table1.field1 = table2.field1
```

But i also want to delate all the row from this table who are not in this UPDATE for have something like :

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id not IN (UPDATE ...)
```

Their is a way to do that in one optimize sql request or i have to do it in two request?

Thanks

Comment: WHERE id not IN (select ...)

Comment: So i have to do it in 2 requestest i can't just delete the line who are not effected by my UPDATE?

Comment: let's wait guru, but I think that combining remove with update can not be in the same query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it in two request as they are two different operation DML operations:

First fire your update statement:

```
UPDATE table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.fk_table1 SET table1.field1 = table2.field1
```

Then fire your delete request by converting update in select:

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id not IN (Select...)
```

Note: Use select with same condition in update command to get the list of records which are updated in first statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query-

```
DELETE FROM tbl1.* FROM 
table1 AS tbl1 
LEFT JOIN table2 AS tbl2 ON table1.id = table2.fk_table1 
WHERE tbl2.id IS NULL
```

But it will be slow as per table size and create locking so you should do that first fetch all id from table1 and then delete them.

```
SELECT tbl1.id FROM 
table1 AS tbl1 
LEFT JOIN table2 AS tbl2 ON table1.id = table2.fk_table1 
WHERE tbl2.id IS NULL
```

Now delete these ids either put in clause or multiple chunks as per no of records.

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id IN ();
```